# how i can make the element's direction to right Css

Tags: css, styled-components

Hi I want to make the element's direction to the right (row)
instead of going down(column)

[image: demo]

```
width: '200px',
        backgroundColor: '#fafafa',
        border: "none",
        borderRadius:'10px',
        whiteSpace: 'nowrap',
        textOverflow: `ellipsis`,
        height:"20px",
        overflow: 'hidden',
        display:'flex',
        flexDeriction:"row",
        flexFlow:"row nowrap",
        justifyContent: 'flex-end'
```

Answer (score 0):

change `justifyContent` to `alignItems` with the same value

Comment: the problem now is the elements are compressed

Comment: [![Capture.png](https://i.postimg.cc/vZVk47wW/Capture.png)](https://postimg.cc/VJzDTC66)